# How do I close a database connection being used to produce a streaming result in a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming, database-connection

I have been unable to find any documentation on properly closing database connections in WCF service operations.  I have a service that returns a streamed response through the following method.

```
public virtual Message GetData()
{
    string sqlString = BuildSqlString();
    SqlConnection conn = Utils.GetConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
    XmlReader xr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();

    Message msg = Message.CreateMessage(
        OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageVersion,
        GetResponseAction(),
        xr);

    return msg;
}
```

I cannot close the connection within the method or the streaming of the response message will be terminated.  Since control returns to the WCF system after the completion of that method, I don't know how I can close that connection afterwards.  Any suggestions or pointers to additional documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, actually.  Unfortunately, one for which I believe there is no good answer.  There's actually an active [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93846/sqlcommand-executexmlreader-method-should-have-an-overload-for-commandbehavior-closeconnection-just-like-the-sqlcommand-executereader-method#details) ticket about this very issue.

Normally, if you want to stream results and you just need a regular `SqlDataReader`, you can use the [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) overload that takes a `CommandBehavior`, and specifically `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`.  If a reader is created using this command behavior, then when you `Close` (or `Dispose`) the reader, it also closes the underlying connection, so you never have to worry about disposing the `SqlConnection`.

Unfortunately, there's no equivalent overload of `ExecuteXmlReader`.  You have to dispose the `SqlConnection` explicitly.

One way around this would be to implement your own `XmlReader` descendant, wrapping the real `XmlReader` obtained from `ExecuteXmlReader` and forcing the connection closed on close.

The basic idea is just to derive from `XmlReader` and wrap both the real `XmlReader` and the `SqlConnection` itself.  Something like this:

```
class SqlXmlReader : XmlReader
{
    private SqlConnection connection;
    private XmlReader reader;

    public SqlXmlReader(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        if (cmd == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cmd");
        this.connection = cmd.Connection;
        this.reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

This takes the connection and the reader directly from the `SqlCommand` so there's no chance of a connection/reader mismatch.  You need to implement the rest of the `XmlReader` methods and properties too - it's just a lot of boring method proxying:

```
    public override int AttributeCount
    {
        get { return reader.AttributeCount; }
    }

    public override string BaseURI
    {
        get { return reader.BaseURI; }
    }

    public override int Depth
    {
        get { return reader.Depth; }
    }

    public override bool EOF
    {
        get { return reader.EOF; }
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(int i)
    {
        return reader.GetAttribute(i);
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(string name, string namespaceURI)
    {
        return reader.GetAttribute(name, namespaceURI);
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(string name)
    {
        return reader.GetAttribute(name);
    }

    public override bool HasValue
    {
        get { return reader.HasValue; }
    }

    public override bool IsEmptyElement
    {
        get { return reader.IsEmptyElement; }
    }

    public override string LocalName
    {
        get { return reader.LocalName; }
    }

    public override string LookupNamespace(string prefix)
    {
        return reader.LookupNamespace(prefix);
    }

    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name, string ns)
    {
        return reader.MoveToAttribute(name, ns);
    }

    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name)
    {
        return reader.MoveToAttribute(name);
    }

    public override bool MoveToElement()
    {
        return reader.MoveToElement();
    }

    public override bool MoveToFirstAttribute()
    {
        return reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    }

    public override bool MoveToNextAttribute()
    {
        return reader.MoveToNextAttribute();
    }

    public override XmlNameTable NameTable
    {
        get { return reader.NameTable; }
    }

    public override string NamespaceURI
    {
        get { return reader.NamespaceURI; }
    }

    public override XmlNodeType NodeType
    {
        get { return reader.NodeType; }
    }

    public override string Prefix
    {
        get { return reader.Prefix; }
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        return reader.Read();
    }

    public override bool ReadAttributeValue()
    {
        return reader.ReadAttributeValue();
    }

    public override ReadState ReadState
    {
        get { return reader.ReadState; }
    }

    public override void ResolveEntity()
    {
        reader.ResolveEntity();
    }

    public override string Value
    {
        get { return reader.Value; }
    }
```

Dull, dull, dull, but it works.  This reader will close the connection for you when it's done, same as a `SqlDataReader` opened with `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`.

Last thing to do would be to create an extension method to make this easier to use:

```
public static class SqlExtensions
{
    public static XmlReader ExecuteSafeXmlReader(this SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        return new SqlXmlReader(cmd);
    }
}
```

Once you have this, instead of writing:

```
XmlReader xr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
```

You write:

```
XmlReader xr = cmd.ExecuteSafeXmlReader();
```

That's it.  Now when WCF closes your reader, it will automatically close the underlying connection.

(Disclaimer: This hasn't officially been tested, but I can see no reason why it wouldn't work, unless WCF does not actually close the reader. Be sure to actually test this against a live SQL connection to make sure that it really doesn't leak connections.)

Comment: @Aaron: shouldn't you implement `IDisposable` on that class?

Comment: @John: The base `XmlReader` already implements `IDisposable`, and within that method invokes the virtual `Close` method, so in this case it's not necessary to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some form of a [Duplex Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) or [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx) based service.  This would allow you to make the request in one call and keep the SqlConnection opened until a `Disconnect()` style call is made.  This disconnect could `.Dispose()` of the related SQL objects.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into making your service class implement the IDispose